# Share just one of multiple spreadsheet saved in excel on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, sharing, spreadsheet

Hi I have a excel file saved on the sharepoint and it has 5 spreadsheet. I want to give people access just to one of the spreasheets saved on the same excel file, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this would be by protecting the other sheets in Excel. There is no way for SharePoint to differentiate permissions per worksheet unfortunately.

Another way would be to split it into different Excel files.